# Excel: Create conditional format when values different

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create a conditional formatting that would highlight in red when the value in the second column is the different as the first.

Example Table

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
1         200
20        50
30        30
4         4
```

In the previous example, I would need the cells for the first two records to highlight red because they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional Formatting - New Rule - Use a formula to determine which cells to format

```
=NOT(A1=B1)
```

Just apply it to column A

For N/A you can use

```
=ISNA(OR(A1,B2))
```

Comment: I have simplified it in the example, but I am comparing two cells with vlookup formulas that return a price or #N/A. with your suggestion it isn't formatting anything.

Comment: That's not at all what your example shows, but I gave another formula.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Conditional Formatting](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/26).

First, click on **A1**, then from Excel Home tab, click on **Conditional Formattin**g and select **New Rule**.

From the New Formatting Rule dialog, select **Format only cells that contain**.

Now under the rule description and do the following:

1. First option : **Cell Value**
2. Second option: **not equal to**
3. Third option: **=B1**

Now, click on **Format** button and select the format that you need the **A1** cell to change to, and whenever is the value of **A1** cell is not equal to B1. Then click **OK** to all dialog.

Now, use **Format Painter** to copy **A1** conditional format and then click on **column A**. This will make all cells in column A.

That's it.